# C# Multiple index formats

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, indexing

I am writing a class for performing some advanced computations using matrices. I have written a simple 2D indexer as follows (and before the question is asked, there is a reason for using a 1D array instead of a 2D array):

```
public double this[int row, int col]
{
    get { int index = col + (row * columns); return contents[index]; }
    set
    {
        double inter = value;
        int index = col + (row * columns);
        contents[index] = inter;
        clearDependent();
    }
}
```

However, it would be of great use to me if I also had a simple 1D accessor, for cases where the matrix is a row/column vector, like this:

```
private double this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (rows == 1 || columns == 1)
        {
            return contents[index];
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Matrix is not a row or column vector.");
        }
    }
    set
    {
        if (rows == 1 || columns == 1)
        {
            contents[index] = value;
            clearDependent();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: Matrix is not a row or column vector.");
        }
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I would like it to be used as below:

```
Matrix M = new Matrix("Stuff that initializes a 4x1 matrix");
double some_value = M[3];
Matrix N - new Matrix("Stuff that initializes a 4x4 matrix");
double some_value = N[2,3];
```

However, when I insert something like

```
M[3]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error   CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required 
formal parameter 'col' of 'Matrix.this[int, int]'
```

Is there a possible workaround, or should I give up on this?

I couldn't find this issue anywhere else, if it's answered somewhere, please let me know.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/319825/multiple-indexers-in-csharp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+There+is+no+argument+given+that+corresponds+to+the+required+formal+parameter Umm... 154 results.

Comment: Your indexer with 1 value is declared `private`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prop definition is private. Was that intentional?